# How to trigger a external page load when a click happen inside an iframe?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, window, fancybox

I have a website that needs to logged from a external page that is inside an Iframe that is on fancybox window, but I want right after the user press the login button the main page that host the iframe  reloads within loged website content, is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your iframe:

```
<script>
    window.parent.location = "page_to_load.php";
</script>
```

Comment: You don't even need the window. Or you could have a method in your parent source like `login()` that you could call with `parent.login();`